# Riemann--Stieltjes integral wrt. uniformly vanishing integrator?

Tags: integration

I'm interested in uniform limits of Riemann--Stieltjes integrals of the form:

$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \int_0^t f(s)\,\text{d}G^N(s)$

where $f(t)$ is non-increasing (but not necessarily continuous) and $|f(t)| \leq C$ for all $t \in [0,T]$. Also $\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |G^N(t)| \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. The $G^N(t)$ may not be continuous or monotone but it is known that the integrals exist and are finite for all $N$.

My intuition is that the above limit of the integrals should be zero but I seem unable to prove this... perhaps I am wrong. Does anyone have any proof ideas or indeed a counterexample?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The limit is indeed zero. This follows after  integration by parts 
$$\int_0^t f\,dG^N = f(t)G^N(t)-f(0)G^N(0)-\int_0^t G^N\,df \tag1$$
because the uniform smallness of $G^N$ makes all three terms in (1)
 converge to $0$.

(You may have to work to justify the integration by parts, depending on how much of the Riemann-Stieltjes theory you have at your disposal.)